# I want to loop through asp.net control checkboxlist and retrieve value of checked items so that I can store id in database

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
public void InsertHobbies()
{
        //foreach(object obj in chkEmpHobbyList.Controls)
        //{
        //    CheckBox chkbox = (CheckBox)obj;
        //    if(chkbox.Checked)
        //    {
        //        hobby objhobby = new hobby();

        //        objhobby.insertHobby((Convert.ToInt32(chkbox.ID)),empid);
        //    }
        //}

        foreach (ListItem listItem in chkEmpHobbyList.Items)
        {
            if (listItem.Selected)
            {
                hobby objhobby = new hobby();
                objhobby.insertHobby((Convert.ToInt32(/what to give/)), empid);
            }

        }
}
```

/***aspx code****/

```
<asp:CheckBoxList ID="chkEmpHobbyList" runat="server">
        </asp:CheckBoxList>
```

/**bind list with database **/

```
public List<hobby> GetHobbies()
    {
        DBlist obj = new DBlist();
        DataSet ds = obj.getdata("str_gethobby", null);
        List<hobby> hobbies = new List<hobby>();
        foreach (DataRow orow in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
        {
            hobby dlist = new hobby();
            dlist.HobbyName = orow["hobby_name"].ToString();
            dlist.Hobbyvalue = int.Parse(orow["id"].ToString());
            hobbies.Add(dlist);
        }
        return hobbies;
    }
```

/****/

```
 hobby dlist = new hobby();
    List<hobby> hobbies = dlist.GetHobbies();
    chkEmpHobbyList.DataSource = hobbies;
    chkEmpHobbyList.DataTextField = "HobbyName";
    chkEmpHobbyList.DataValueField = "Hobbyvalue";
    chkEmpHobbyList.DataBind();
```

I want to loop through asp.net control checkboxlist and retrieve value of check items so that I can store id in database. How would I get Id of checked checkboxes?

Comment: what's the problem?

Comment: i am not getting selected checkbox id

Comment: Why use `Selected`, not `Checked`

Comment: I bind checkboxlist with database

Comment: put your `.aspx` code in your post as well so we get an idea of how you've used checklist controls there.

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate over your CheckBoxList and get Value/Text like this:

```
        for (int i = 0; i < chkEmpHobbyList.Items.Count; i++)
        {
            if (chkEmpHobbyList.Items[i].Selected)
            {
              string value=chkEmpHobbyList.Items[i].Value;//it will return Value, You can also get .Text
            }
        }
```

Hope it helps!